# RxJava Kotlin combineLatest timeout before first element

Tags: android, kotlin, timeout, rx-java2, combinelatest

I'm developing an android app in Kotlin. I have got 3 realtime data observables. The data comes from Firestore. They are wrapped inside RxJava's Observable.combineLatest() method. I want to set a timeout on a first data retrieval.

I have tried to set timeout functions on each of observables but they throw TimeoutException after initial data from all 3 observables has been loaded.

```
private fun retrieveAllData() {
Observable.combineLatest(
                retrieveDataObservable1().timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                retrieveDataObservable2().timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                retrieveDataObservable3().timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                Function3<String, String, Boolean, Triple<String, String, Boolean>>
                { firstResult, secondResult, ThirdResult ->
                    Triple(firstResult, secondResult, ThirdResult)
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        { Log.d(TAG, "success") },
                        { throwable -> Log.d(TAG, "error", throwable) }
                )
}

private fun retrieveDataObservable1(): Observable<String> {
        return Observable.create<String> { emitter ->
            val listener = dataRef1.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
                if (e != null) {
                    emitter.onError(e)
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }
                emitter.onNext("some value")
            }
         emitter.setCancellable { listener.remove() }
     }
}
```

I expect a TimeoutExceiption from Observable.combineLatest() on initial retrieval if at least one of the Observables didn't emit any item in 10 seconds.
If all observables emitted data successfuly at least once then there shouldn't be TimeoutException.

Comment: I think you will find a few working solutions for you problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304339/rxjava-only-check-the-first-response-item-with-timeout).

Comment: @adrianbukros I've seen this one, but sadly couldn't get it working in Kotlin

Comment: Tried to make you an example. Can you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think this should work for you:

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.functions.Function
import io.reactivex.functions.Function3
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

Observable.combineLatest(
    firstObservable,
    secondObservable,
    thirdObservable,
    Function3<String, String, String, String> { first, second, third -> "$first$second$third" })
    .timeout<String, String>(
       Observable.empty<String>().delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
       Function { Observable.never<String>() }
    )
    .subscribe {
        println("$it")
    }
```

The first parameter of the `timeout()` operator is an `Observable` for the first item timeout. In our case it's 10 sec. For the upcoming items it's a function that returns `Observable.never()` for all item so it will never trigger a timeout.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!